# How to align image as center in tinymce?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using jquery tinymce. once i insert an image it is aligned left as default. How can i align it as center as default.

```
if (tinyMCE.activeEditor != null && tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() == false)
{
    var content=tinyMCE.get('faq_answer').getContent()+"<img id='"+faq_media_id+"' src='"+path+"' title='"title"' align='"middle"' alt='"alternate"' width='"150"' height='"150"' >";
    tinyMCE.get('faq_answer').setContent(content);
    //alert('tiny: '+content);
}
```

In my above code i am adding image into tinymce. If i give align="midde" not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you remember your question on howto predefine the editors default font size. This one is similar.
You will have to set the css according to your need in the css file you reference useing the content_css setting.

it should look like

```
img {
  align: middle;
}
```

**EDIT:** Even though the easiest and most waterproof method to set the css style is to use the css file content_css reffers to, you may use:

```
$(ed.getBody()).find('img').css('align','middle');
```

**EDIT2:** You need to set your qoutes right:

```
var content=tinyMCE.get('faq_answer').getContent()+"<img id='"+faq_media_id+"' src='"+path+"' title='title' align='middle' alt='alternate' width='150' height='150' >";
```

**EDIT3:**   This will work:

```
$(ed.getBody()).find('img').css('display','block');
$(ed.getBody()).find('img').css('margin','0px auto');
```

Comment: alignment middle not works for me. once i see in firebug align="middle" only shows but still left aligned in appearence

Comment: hmmm, try style="align:middle;"

Comment: If i assign style="position: absolute; right: 350;" aligned center but i need appropriate code why align: middle not woks....

Comment: align middle seems to be deprecated

Comment: wierd: $(ed.getBody()).find('img').attr('align','right'); works, but places the img to the right .

Comment: I know align left and right works. My question is why align middle not works

Comment: as i said it is deprecated, have allok at my EDIT3 for a working solution